# Custom Rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hl7-fhir

```
class EHRObservation < ApplicationRecord
end
```

```
class EHRPatient < ApplicationRecord
end
```

```
pp EHRObservation.last.data

"resource"=>
  {"identifier"=>[{"system"=>"https:fhir-myrecord.cerner.com", "value"=>"M197427375"}],
   "code"=>{"text"=>"Height Z-Score"},
   "comments"=>"^~:!ZScore Source -CDC-WHO",
   "subject"=>{"reference"=>"Patient/e467f71f186f"},
   "encounter"=>{"reference"=>"Encounter/e467f71f186f3a8ea2702798f2fb3f587f0d0af5cc5a84c9"},
   "effectiveDateTime"=>"2021-01-19T15:45:32.000Z",
   "meta"=>{"lastUpdated"=>"2021-06-11T10:25:02.320Z", "versionId"=>"9000000000002"},
   "id"=>"e467f71f186fffac81477fec82dc9dca96c9987960bafe7b",
   "text"=>
    {"div"=>
      "<div><p><b>Observation</b></p><p><b>Patient</b>: 12724065</p><p><b>Status</b>: Final</p><p><b>Category</b>: Vital Signs</p><p><b>Code</b>: Height Z-Score</p><p><b>Result</b>: 10.00</p><p><b>Date</b>: Jan 19, 2021  3:45 P.M. UTC</p></div>",
     "status"=>"generated"},
   "category"=>{"coding"=>[{"system"=>"http://hl7.org/fhir/observation-category", "code"=>"vital-signs", "display"=>"Vital Signs"}], "text"=>"Vital Signs"},
   "issued"=>"2021-01-19T16:02:12.000Z",
   "resourceType"=>"Observation",
   "status"=>"final",
   "valueQuantity"=>{"value"=>10}}
```

```
pp EHRPatient.last.data

{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "id": "e467f71f186f",
  "meta": {
    "extension": [ {
      "url": "http://hapifhir.io/fhir/StructureDefinition/resource-meta-source",
      "valueUri": "#3f6016452661aabf"
    } ],
    "versionId": "1",
    "lastUpdated": "2019-08-21T18:25:59.737+00:00"
  },
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><div class=\"hapiHeaderText\"> Sarita123 </div><table class=\"hapiPropertyTable\"><tbody><tr><td>Date of birth</td><td><span>21 August 2019</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div>"
  },
  "name": [ {
    "given": [ "  Sarita123" ]
  } ],
  "telecom": [ {
    "system": "phone",
    "use": "home"
  } ],
  "gender": "male",
  "birthDate": "2019-08-21"
}
```

Above is a kind of EHR data that I am dealing with. If you notice every observation belongs to patient. So I want to define `belongs_to :ehr_patient` but since these are not traditional SQL models I couldn't do that. Then how could I define custom relationship? My ultimate goal would be like `EHRObservation.last.patient` should return `EHRpatient` record.

Comment: Please show database schema

Comment: Is this a raw `jsonb` field, or something? Could you map data into a schema, instead of (or in addition to) dumping the whole structure into a single field?

Comment: For example, as a bare minimum, could you have something like: `EHRPatient#resource_type` and `EHRPatient#resource_id` columns, extracted from the raw data?